# What is the correct way to pass ApiKey and UserAddress with $http in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

```
$http({         
     url: "/api/v1/login/get?username="+$scope.UserName+"&password="+$scope.Password,
     method: 'GET',
     data:{
        'ApiKey': '645rc5dsfdf4566444e34e9b205d6f91683790927e83459e2ac8a8f3',
        'UserAddress': '177.70.5.2'
     },        
 }).then(function (response) {
     $scope.data = response.data;        

 }).catch(function (response) {               
 });
```

With my http request I am passing ApiKey and UserAddress in data but it's not working and goes into catch.I have also tried to put it in headers and Params but getting same ? Whats is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass API key and User Address as a header instead of data. in $http({}) function.

$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/login/get?username="+$scope.UserName+"&password="+$scope.Password', headers: {'ApiKey': '645rc5dsfdf4566444e34e9b205d6f91683790927e83459e2ac8a8f3','UserAddress':'177.70.5.2'} }).

Comment: By using POST man rest client is it working? if yes please check the format what you are passing, i mean where you are passing the APIKey and UserAddress as a header or request body?

Answer (score 0):

Header should work.
Try this:

```
$http({
method: 'GET', 
url: '/api/v1/login/get?username='+$scope.UserName+'&password='+$scope.Password, 
headers: {
          'ApiKey': '645rc5dsfdf4566444e34e9b205d6f91683790927e83459e2ac8a8f3',
          'UserAddress': '177.70.5.2'
      }
});
```